# Does OpenMp have support for Real Time Multiprocessor Computing?

Tags: parallel-programming, multi-core

I am working on a real time multiprocessor scheduling algorithm. I found very few results via google research related to it. A few simulators are available but are not robust enough.

OpenMp is an API I have previously used for small parallel application development.  But I am not sure if it provides any support for real time parallel computing which involves time related parameters such as task period, deadline etc.

Are those features available in OpenMp?  If not, are the underpinnings available so I could extend OpenMp instead?

Answer (score -1):

OpenMP is used in embedded systems programming, for instance on the TI Keystone processor. So it may be possible to do real time multiprocessing with it.

What hardware will you be using?

I opened a question for you on the OpenMP Forum. You can follow it there.
http://forum.openmp.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2091

Regards,
Matthijs